# Update with Multiple Values in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

How to Update with Multiple Values in Entity Frame Work Core.

This is my table

| Destination Id | SiteCode ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 4 |

I need to update like this

| Destination Id | SiteCode ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 |

`DestinationId` and `SiteCodeID` are foreign keys. `DestinationId` is referring to the `Destination` table (`ID`), `SiteCodeId` is referring to the `SiteCode` table (`ID`).

This is Destination.cs

```
public class Destination
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public List<DealDestination> DealDestinations { get; set; }
    public List<SiteDestination> SiteDestinations { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<int> SiteCode { get; set; }
}

public class SiteDestination
{
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    public int SiteCodeId { get; set; }

    public SiteCode SiteCode { get; set; }

    public Destination Destination { get; set; }
}
```

I did like this that I removed that data and add new data. But it is wrong. I have to update.

```
public async Task<Destination> Update(Destination destination)
{
        _catalogDbContext.Destinations.Update(destination);

        var siteDestination = new SiteDestination
        {
        };

        var oldSiteDestinations = await _catalogDbContext.SiteDestinations.Where(i => i.DestinationId == destination.Id).ToListAsync();
        _catalogDbContext.RemoveRange(oldSiteDestinations);

        foreach (var Id in destination.SiteCode)
        {
            var siteCodeId = _catalogDbContext.SiteCodes.Include(i => i.Id);

            siteDestination.SiteCodeId = Id;
            siteDestination.DestinationId = destination.Id;

            await _catalogDbContext.SiteDestinations.AddAsync(siteDestination);
            await _catalogDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(true);

        return destination;
}
```

How can I update with multiple values? Give me some examples or ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

This question has lead to other questions. In order to get this solved, let's take it all the way from controller to db.

Question is about posting a JSON like this:

```
{"id": 1,  "siteCode": [1,2,9] }
```

and receive the exact same JSON after a round-trip to db.

Instead of using an EF entity model as request model, let's create a view model like shown below and clean up the entity classes a little bit (shown at the end):

```
public class DestinationVm
{
    [Required]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public ICollection<int> SiteCode { get; set; }
}
```

Controller used during testing. Business logic is included in controller class for simplicity. Put method is kept simple and is not by the book.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DestinationController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly SchoolContext _catalogDbContext;

    public DestinationController(SchoolContext catalogDbContext)
    {
        _catalogDbContext = catalogDbContext;
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult<DestinationVm> PutDestination([FromBody] DestinationVm viewModel)
    {
        var updatedEntity = Update(viewModel);

        var returnModel = new DestinationVm
        {
            Id = updatedEntity.Id,
            SiteCode = updatedEntity.SiteDestinations
                .Select(it => it.SiteCodeId)
                .ToArray()
        };
        return Ok(returnModel);
    }

    private Destination Update(DestinationVm viewModel)
    {
        var destinationFromDb = _catalogDbContext.Destinations
            .Include(x => x.SiteDestinations)
            .Single(it => it.Id == viewModel.Id);

        // delete children not present in view model
        foreach (var siteDestination in destinationFromDb.SiteDestinations
            .Where(it => viewModel.SiteCode
                .All(x => x != it.SiteCodeId)).ToList())
        {
            destinationFromDb.SiteDestinations.Remove(siteDestination);
        }

        // insert children not present in db
        foreach (var currentSiteCode in viewModel.SiteCode
            .Where(it => destinationFromDb.SiteDestinations
                .All(x => x.SiteCodeId != it)))
        {
            destinationFromDb.SiteDestinations.Add(new SiteDestination
            {
                SiteCodeId = currentSiteCode
            });
        }
        
        _catalogDbContext.SaveChanges();
        return destinationFromDb;
    }
}
```

Many-to-many relation is defined liked this (required because question is about Core 3.1):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SiteDestination>()
        .HasKey(e => new {e.DestinationId, e.SiteCodeId});

    modelBuilder.Entity<SiteDestination>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Destination)
        .WithMany(p => p.SiteDestinations);

    modelBuilder.Entity<SiteDestination>()
        .HasOne(e => e.SiteCode)
        .WithMany(p => p.SiteDestinations);
}
```

Model classes used during testing:

```
public class SiteCode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SiteDestination> SiteDestinations { get; } = new List<SiteDestination>();

    // some more properties here
}

public class SiteDestination
{
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    public Destination Destination { get; set; }

    public int SiteCodeId { get; set; }
    public SiteCode SiteCode { get; set; }
}

public class Destination
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SiteDestination> SiteDestinations { get; } = new List<SiteDestination>();
}
```

Comment: This gives error as "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')".
There is some error in this line `foreach (var currentIncomingSiteDestination in incomingDestination.SiteDestinations
        .Where(it => it.DestinationId == 0))`.

Comment: @hanushi: In class `Destionation`, please change `public List<SiteDestination> SiteDestinations { get; set; }` to `public List<SiteDestination> SiteDestinations { get; set; } = new List<SiteDestination>();` The error occurs because you're not populating this field. BR

Comment: Thank you. It works. Why this line? `var currentSiteDestinationFromDb = _catalogDbContext.SiteDestinations
                    .First(it => it.SiteCodeId == currentIncomingSiteDestination.SiteCodeId);`

Comment: But i need to update SiteDestination table too. How can i do that?. I have already mention ed that table. see above. i need to update like that. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @hanushi: I've tested the code. Table SiteDestination should be updated automatic when adding/removing entries from SiteDestinations. Please see config and test code in my updated answer.

Comment: I sent `{
    "id": 218,
    "siteCode": [9,1]
}` . and The Result is `{
        "id": 218,
        "siteDestinations": [ ],
        "siteCode": [ 9,1]
    }`
Is this right? How should i send?
My destination.cs 
`public int Id { get; set; }
 public List<SiteDestination> SiteDestinations { get; } = new List<SiteDestination>();
  [NotMapped]
 public List<int> SiteCode { get; set; }`. Do i need this line `[NotMapped]
 public List<int> SiteCode { get; set; }`.

Comment: @hanushi: Added view model and controller as well to my answer, everything is running as expected. BR